# How to setup Starling to use full screen iphone4 and iphone5

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am considering updating my app to take advantage of iphone5's bigger screen but not sure how to achieve this is as3.

I have tried a few suggestions online however unable to get them working. The app works and looks fine with no modification but just letterboxes top and bottom.

This is my code:

```
var stageWidth:int   = Constants.STAGEWIDTH; // Hardcoded to 320
var stageHeight:int  = Constants.STAGEHEIGHT; // Hardcoded to 480
var screenWidth:int  = stage.fullScreenWidth;
var screenHeight:int = stage.fullScreenHeight;

Constants.FULLSCREENWIDTH = stage.fullScreenWidth;
Constants.FULLSCREENHEIGHT = stage.fullScreenHeight;

var iOS:Boolean = Capabilities.manufacturer.indexOf("iOS") != -1;
Starling.multitouchEnabled = false;
Starling.handleLostContext = true; 

var viewPort:Rectangle =  new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
var startupImage:Sprite = createStartupImage(viewPort, screenWidth > 320);
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a launch image named Default-568h@2x.png to the package. The resolution of this launch image should be 1136*640 pixels. In case you are already using a namespace schema for your launch images, you can just append ”-568h@2x” to the namespace schema.

taken from
http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/07/deploying-air-apps-on-iphone-5/

also, stageWidth on starling will be 568 now, not 480 like in 3.5" screens

try to hardcode this now.

```
var screenWidth:int  = 640;
var screenHeight:int = 1136;
var viewPort:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

starling = new Starling(Game, stage, viewPort);
starling.stage.stageWidth  = 320;
starling.stage.stageHeight = 568;
```

If this works, it means that you get wrong stageWith and stageHeight from stage.stageWidth.

here you can see how to correctly get stageView and stageHeight but that is different topic

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3712344

Comment: Hi thanks. I added the image but I was meaning utilise the entire screen height instead of letterbox.

Comment: when you launch the game now, is the splash screen that you just added fullscreen?

Comment: Yes it is fullscreen but then changes to 640x960 but letterboxed top and bottom.

Comment: height is 568 in iphone 5